# Why does sbt fail with "object SQLContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql"?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to use Spark SQL for which I have used the following import:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
```

but it is creating the error:

> object SQLContext is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

I am using SBT as the build tool. The content of the sbt file is as follows:

```
name := "stream-demo"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
val sparkVersion = "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion)
```

Comment: Could you provide your codes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the environment yo use to compile the code did **not** refresh itself and loaded `spark-sql` module.

Please leave your sbt session and start over.

You could also do `reload` while in `sbt` session (so you won't destroy the JVM sbt runs on and so make the reload faster).